# Thread starting just after object has been dealloc'ed

Tags: iphone, ios, multithreading

I have a situation in my iOS application.

I'm making a request to a web api and I'm doing so in a background thread. I have a class called Service that has this method:

```
- (void)searchForRoutesFrom:(NSNumber *)startStationId
                         to:(NSNumber *)endStationId
                   delegate:(id<WAMSServiceDelegate>)delegateOrNil
{
    RouteSearchRequest *request = [[RouteSearchRequest alloc] init];
    ...request populate ...
    [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(searchForRoutesInTheBackground:) 
                             toTarget:self withObject:request];
}

- (void)searchForRoutesInTheBackground:(RouteSearchRequest *)request
{
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    ...make the request and call back...
}
```

This is working well, but if the user decides to leave the View (using this Service), just before the thread has starte, the Service object is deallocated. When the thread starts it will try and invoke searchForRoutesInTheBackground method and my application will crash.

What other approaches could I use to running this thread and dealing with the calling object being released.

Answer (score 0):

You could `retain` the calling object before starting the thread, and releasing it at the end of its processing (just before returning).

```
 - (void)searchForRoutesFrom:(NSNumber *)startStationId
                     to:(NSNumber *)endStationId
               delegate:(id<WAMSServiceDelegate>)delegateOrNil
{
RouteSearchRequest *request = [[RouteSearchRequest alloc] init];
...request populate ...

[self retain];
[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(searchForRoutesInTheBackground:) 
                         toTarget:self withObject:request];
}

- (void)searchForRoutesInTheBackground:(RouteSearchRequest *)request
{
NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
...make the request and call back...

[self release];
}
```

If you used blocks, that would be done automatically for you, but retaining/releasing is pretty easy to manage this case.

Comment: The problem is not the request, rather it's trying to start a thread on "self" which actually gets released, so the searchFroRoutesInTheBackground method is called on a deallocated object.

Comment: I see, sorry for the misunderstanding.... what about [self retain]/[self release], then?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I would answer you correctly according to your situation due to insufficient information on your logic, but those scenarios I handle in a different way. What I do is I create separate class (model as of MVC) for communicating with a web service with methods that initiate the requests and handle the callbacks. When the callback executes there are different scenarios - (either persist the result using CoreData and my UI catches this event and updates (if visible), or a block is passed as an argument to the method that makes the request and in the callback is called and the block is executed, and usually the block starts with `if(!self.view.window) return;` which means nothing will happen if the current view is not visible). But in both situations my requests and callbacks are totally independent of the UI and therefore problems like yours does not occur.

Answer (score 0):

> but if the user decides to leave the View (using this Service), just
>   before the thread has starte, the Service object is deallocated. When
>   the thread starts it will try and invoke
>   searchForRoutesInTheBackground method and my application will crash.

This is not possible. See the [documentation for +detachNewThreadSelector:toTarget:withObject:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsthread_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000311-CHDEBGEC). It says

> The objects aTarget and anArgument are retained during the execution of the detached thread, then released.

Which means that it is retained when you call `detachNewThreadSelector:toTarget:withObject:`. So if the object was valid at that moment, it will be valid until the new thread finishes executing.

If something bad is happening, you must be doing memory management wrong somewhere else. e.g. 1) the object is already deallocated by the time `detachNewThreadSelector:toTarget:withObject:` is called, or 2) you are over-releasing the object somewhere else where you are not supposed to.